# Developer playground in lightning component library

Tags: lightning-web-components

I  want to use the `playground` in the lightning component library https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components.![When I link the lightning component library to my org than the `Playground`   option shows.[image]

when I click the playground then it takes me to the https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/overview/components.I am unable to find the reason behind it. thanks

Answer (score 6):

Sometime back salesforce deprecated LWC [playground](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/11/ecosystem-innovation-with-lightning-web-components):

> With all the innovation WebComponents.dev brings to the LWC ecosystem this does mean that we will be phasing out our LWC Playground on February 1, 2021.

Salesforce invested in [WebComponents.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/create/lwc) that a template for LWC. It is better alternative than playground.

Comment: so its better to use this <https://webcomponents.dev/edit/mjWI08UrpxiX6qUkgPlX/src/app.html >??

Comment: That is correct as its the next best alternative to playground, nice thing is you can save and share them with others